# Using Hbase with C#

Tags: c#, vb.net, hbase

How can I use a Hbase database with C#/VB.NET ?
(use=connect, query, get the result, insert, update, delete)

I don't find useful answers with google.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've just published HBase C# Thrift binding as nuget package.
Alternatively you can grab code/binaries from bitbucket: https://bitbucket.org/vadim/hbase-sharp/downloads

Comment: Thats great Vadim! It seems to be far old. Where can I get updated version of HBase-Sharp to support HBase's latest version?

Comment: @DineshKumarP I created a fork of above for .net standard. https://www.nuget.org/packages/HBase.Thrift.Core/

Answer (score 2):

From the [description](http://hadoop.apache.org/hbase/):

> A REST-ful Web service gateway that
>   supports XML, Protobuf, and binary
>   data encoding options

There's a [protobuf port for .NET](http://code.google.com/p/protobuf-net/) and there are many XML manipulation APIs built-in.

Answer (score 0):

HBase C# Thrift works nicely. Just download the latest thrift-0.9.2.exe, thrift.dll and Hbase.thrift file on your windows machine. You can generate the required c# files with the following command:

```
thrift-0.9.2.exe -gen csharp Hbase.thrift
```

You will get the following files as a result:

```
AlreadyExists.cs
BatchMutation.cs
ColumnDescriptor.cs
Hbase.cs
IllegalArgument.cs
IOError.cs
Mutation.cs
TAppend.cs
TCell.cs
TColumn.cs
TIncrement.cs
TRegionInfo.cs
TRowResult.cs
TScan.cs
```

Include them in your project and add thrift.dll to your project references. Short sample code (list tables and insert/update a cell value):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using Thrift.Protocol;
using Thrift.Transport;

namespace bdc
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {            
            // Connection
            var socket = new TSocket("hdp1.localdomain", 9090);
            var transport =new TBufferedTransport(socket);
            var protocol = new TBinaryProtocol(transport);
            Hbase.Client hba = new Hbase.Client(protocol);
            transport.Open();            

            // Get table names
            Console.WriteLine("<-GET LIST OF TABLES->");      
            var tableNames = hba.getTableNames();
            foreach (var tableName in tableNames)
            Console.WriteLine(Encoding.UTF8.GetString(tableName, 0, tableName.Length));            

            // Insert rows       
            Console.WriteLine("<-INSERT->");      
            Mutation _mutation = new Mutation();
            _mutation.IsDelete = false;
            _mutation.Column = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("image:bodyimage");
            _mutation.Value = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("newnew image 2.jpg");

            hba.mutateRow(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("blogposts"), Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("post1"), new List<Mutation> { _mutation }, null);

            // Finished
            Console.WriteLine("<-FINISHED->");  
            Console.ReadKey();                        
        }        
    }
}
```

The above code works nicely with the Hbase installation of the latest Hortonworks Data Platform, running on CentOS 7.

Comment: Unfortunately as of thrift-0.9.3.exe I do not get the TAppend, TColumn, or TIncrement files and I receive an exception in VS regarding the namespace TException not being found.

Comment: I get the same results from version 0.9.2 as well.

Comment: I did not do a full test with 0.9.3 (but will do it in a few days). Although I tested the command (generating cs files) with the latest 0.9.3 and it worked. I got all the files. Please, try to download Hbase.thrift from http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/hbase/trunk/hbase-thrift/src/main/resources/org/apache/hadoop/hbase/thrift/Hbase.thrift?revision=1590152&view=co

Comment: The Hbase.thrift file you recommended resolved the problem. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks. How can i connect with HBase thrift with doAs (impersonation) header.