# how to connect to HBase / Hadoop Database using C#

Tags: c#, hadoop, hbase, hive, azure-hdinsight

Recently, Exploring Microsoft HDInsight Hadoop for Windows.But don't know where to began and start using apache hadoop with c# / asp.net mvc.

i know http://hadoopsdk.codeplex.com/ is best available resource to start, but can't find documentation to start from scratch? like creating cluster,database and then connecting it to C# app.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using Hbase with C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2392457/using-hbase-with-c-sharp)

Answer (score 5):

The easiest way to get started is to use the [HDInsight service on Azure](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/services/hdinsight/) (which is still in preview, but works well). That way you can just log into your azure portal and spin up a cluster, which will be linked to your azure storage.

If you really don't want to go to the cloud, then you can download the HDInsight developer preview package through the [web platform installer](http://www.microsoft.com/web/downloads/platform.aspx), which will create a single node local cluster. Alternatively, if you're interested in 'just hadoop' then you could try using the VMs provided by Hortonworks or Cloudera.

After that, it's probably worth starting with Hive if you are familiar with SQL. The [O'Reilly Definitive Guide to Hadoop](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9780596521981.do) is pretty good on that.

From the .NET point of view, the [hadoopsdk](http://hadoopsdk.codeplex.com/) on codeplex is a good place to start.

As far as very basic connection examples go, try [this blog](http://www.amazedsaint.com/2013/02/a-quick-introduction-to-hadoop-hive-on.html) for an example, but note that the connection for HDInsight is slightly different now it's all using the templeton interface, so this will get you going:

```
var db = new HiveConnection(
        webHCatUri: new Uri("http://localhost:50111"),
        userName: (string) "hadoop", password: (string) null);
var result = db.ExecuteHiveQuery("select * from w3c");
```

If you are looking to do full on MapReduce on HDInsight, then you probably want to take a look at the C# MapReduce examples with the sdk on codeplex.

Note that the default HDInsight install also comes with some good samples, which include a bit of data to play with and some powershell scripts and .NET code to get you started.

Enjoy!

Comment: thank you sir, for the help.
i tried hdinsigh , worked well.
now currently trying to connect my hadoop cluster(resides on ubuntu server on virtualbox) to a C# Application.HDFS works fine,now trying basic crud operations and sqoop to import/export data

Answer (score 1):

You might find the project **HBase-sharp** useful. You can visit their bitbucket [page](https://bitbucket.org/vadim/hbase-sharp) for detailed info. Looks promising to me. It also includes an example. You can find it [here](https://bitbucket.org/vadim/hbase-sharp/src/c9b6f98ec29cbbbde008260fce5abeb6bfddd9a0/example/Program.cs?at=default).

HTH

Comment: thanks for reply, i already checked this project.i need project with good docs.

currently checking http://hadoopsdk.codeplex.com/.

Comment: do you have any thoughts about it ?

Comment: I'm afraid, that would be a bit difficult. Usually Hadoop/Hbase folks prefer non-MS stuff(I feel so) :)

Comment: Since i'm more of Java person, I can't help much with that. Sorry about that. Moreover, I could not find anything about HBase in their documentation. Somehow I feel that Microsoft guys are a bit less HBase  centric. Perhaps they see it as an opponent their own nosql solutions. Well, this is just what I feel. Any thoughts?

Comment: what if i configure hadoop on ubuntu server(virtualbox) ? what will be the steps to connect database to any application ?

Comment: The procedure is almost similar for any client. You need to tell the client where and on which port zookeeper is running. From there client can get rest of the info required to operate on HBase tables. You can google for "hbase clients". This is the official client page : http://hbase.apache.org/book/client.html

Comment: found it http://hadoopsdk.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Simple%20Linq%20To%20Hive%20Query&referringTitle=Home

Answer (score 1):

check this out https://github.com/hdinsight/hbase-sdk-for-net from HDInsight team

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft released a preview of their [.NET ProtoBuf client for Phoenix/Hbase](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Phoenix.Client/) on Nuget.org in June. I've found it worked well but the API was unfamiliar to me. As I learned it, I implemented a .NET Framework System.Data IDbConnection, IDbCommand et al wrapper API around it, named Garuda.Data. It makes access to Phoenix/Hbase from .NET code feel almost like SqlConnection, SqlCommand, etc for SQL Server - Check it out: https://www.nuget.org/packages/Garuda.Data/

Here is the github project repo: https://github.com/dwdii/GarudaUtil

And some example code:

```
using (IDbConnection phConn = new PhoenixConnection())
{
    phConn.ConnectionString = cmdLine.ConnectionString;

    phConn.Open();

    using (IDbCommand cmd = phConn.CreateCommand())
    {
        cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM GARUDATEST";
        using (IDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
        {
            while(reader.Read())
            {
                for(int i = 0; i < reader.FieldCount; i++)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(string.Format("{0}: {1}", reader.GetName(i), reader.GetValue(i)));
                }
            }
        }
    }                        
}
```