# HBASE connection from UFT

Tags: odbc, hbase, thrift, hp-uft

Is anyone worked on connecting HBASE from HP-UFT? It will be helpful if you can guide me to establish the connection and perform the HBASE querying from UFT.

Answer (score 0):

I have not worked on HBASE, but the simple solution would be to search for a code snippet in VBS or C#.  If you find the code in VBS then you can simply copy/paste it in UFT and run it.

If you find .net based code like below, then you can use the DotNetFactory object in UFT.

Below is the same question asked for C# HBASE connection:

[how to connect to HBase / Hadoop Database using C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17866600/how-to-connect-to-hbase-hadoop-database-using-c-sharp)